# Magnetic Encoders - Tips and Tricks

Tags: encoder, magnetics

I am new to encoders in general and I am thinking about using a magnetic encoder in a personal project were I will need to make my own servo, and thus get an absolute position reading (instead of the relative reading provided by an optica encoder) from the magnetic encoder.
Are there any pitfalls one should know? 
How should I know how many resolution (in degrees) a sensor may have? Is it just about its bits output or there are more hidden problems, like the magnet's properties?

(I know people usually ask for help in this site, and general questions get voted down, but I honestly think this is very helpful so people may avoid wasting time and money in ideas they didnt have the proper knowledge to pursue)

Comment: What encoder you think would be appropriate - can you supply a link

Comment: They make absolute mechanical, capacitive, and optical encoders too. Servos usually use a potentiometer as the position sensor.

Comment: @Theran potentiometers tends doesnt have a high accuracy

Comment: @mFeinstein, it depends on the type and quality of the potentiometer. I've seen potentiometers used in some very high-end systems. Encoders start looking more attractive when you need unlimited turns in the same direction. If the goal of the project is just to gain experience making a servo, then an inexpensive pot sounds like a better choice than an expensive encoder. Sensing accuracy beyond what the rest of your system is capable of (for example, because of gear backlash) drives up cost without improving performance.

Comment: @Theran yes there are some precise potentiometers, I will look into this option as well, thank you, but I am just trying to find out more info about magnetic encoders in general.

Comment: @mFeinstein Please read [this whitepaper](http://www.automationdirect.com/static/press/encoder-white-paper.pdf) when you have a chance. Covers quite a bit of ground, especially for encoders in industrial applications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Magnetic encoders for most intents and purposes are an excellent low cost alternative to traditional optical devices.  There are some concerns related to their repeatability, accuracy and jitter but if you are not on the bleeding edge of servo design, they should suit your purposes very well.

If you are looking to purchase an encoder off the shelf as an integrated product, I've used ones from Baumer before with great success (they are a little expensive).  Otherwise for an IC level solution, the most mainstream ones are from AMS (Austria Microsystems).  I know that the AMS devices are often used in automotive applications like accelerator position sensing, steering wheel position sensing, etc.  RLS (Rennishaw) is another IC vendor.

One thing to be careful of when using an IC solution is that the quality of the magnet matters so be sure to use one that is recommended by the manufacturer.  Also placement of this magnet is important, make sure that it is in a non-ferrous shaft like aluminum, Stainless Steel or plastic.

In general for servos, I wouldn't recommend closing a velocity loop on absolute position feedback but rather use quadrature signals.  You can close position loop by accumulating quadrature as well or use absolute position.  The systems that I worked on use absolute feedback only to perform the homing function at power on and then quadrature for everything else.

Comment: Stainless steel is ferrous, just non-magnetic. :-)

Comment: @user28177 Thanks I am just worried about positon, not speed.

Comment: @AnindoGhosh it depends on the stainless steel actually, some can be magnetic, it depends if it's austenitic or Ferritic...

Comment: @mFeinstein **Ferritic != Ferrous**. *Ferrous* = contains significant percentage of Iron, c.f. non-ferrous which doesn't. *Ferritic* = Ferromagnetic types of SS. All SS is ferrous. Some types are also ferritic.

Comment: @AnindoGhosh I am sorry but don't understand your point... you said SS is non-magnetic, and I said some SS alloys can be magnetic (Ferritic) and some alloys are not magnetic (Austenitic) (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stainless_steel )...I never said there is SS with no iron in the alloy

Comment: @mFeinstein Don't worry about it - I was responding to the part of the answer that said "*... a **non-ferrous** shaft like aluminum, Stainless Steel or ...". Ferrous means containing Iron. Stainless Steel contains iron. SS is always a *ferrous* metal - whether it is austenitic or ferritic.

Comment: @AnindoGhosh ohh I see haha I thought you were replying me, since you tagged me ;)

Answer (score -2):

Magnetic encoder generally have a lower resolution than optical encoders. This is because magnets cannot be packed together as the slits of an optical encoder. I have used optical encoders which use quadrature with 60,000 pulses per revolution. And they are very accurate. Another option for you to look at is hall effect encoders but then again, you have limited resolution.

Comment: Hall effect encoders ARE magnetic encoders ;)
And I am finding magnetic encoders with more than 10 bits of resolution

Comment: Magnetic encoders do not need magnets packed in high density, just one - One of the typical technologies involves sensing the varying magnetic field as the shaft magnet goes around. The actual sensing graph is essentially unlimited in resolution, the integrated post-processing electronics (analog and sometimes also digital) and the noise floor determine how many bits of meaningful data can be extracted.